# Using the OR operator in Jquery .find to parse XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm using the following to parse some XML but would like to be able to use OR and add a second variable into the statement:

```
$(data).find("GUIDE:has(STATUS:contains('"+$pubstate+"'))").each(function(){
```

I've tried various ways of doing it but it only seems to work when I have the one variable. What I'm trying to do is write the xml to a table only if it contains the text held one or the other of two variables, which get their values from radio buttons in my html.

Initially I thought it would be formatted like this:

```
$(data).find("GUIDE:has(STATUS:contains('"+$pubstate+"' || '"+$privstate+"' ))").each(function(){
```

Can anyone help with how to format this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$(data).find("GUIDE:has(STATUS:contains('" + $pubstate + "'), STATUS:contains('" + $privstate + "'))").
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So if the variables are set as 'Published' and 'Private' should it find all Guides in the XML which have the words published and private as their status? I've added it in but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: can you give a sample xml

Comment: <GUIDE>
      <GUIDE_ID>111</GUIDE_ID>
      <OWNER_ACCOUNT_ID>1111</OWNER_ACCOUNT_ID>
      <NAME>Test page</NAME>
      <DESCRIPTION>Test page</DESCRIPTION>
      <TAGS></TAGS>
      <STATUS>Unpublished</STATUS>
</GUIDE>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `,` to separate the `:contains` selectors:

```
$(data).find("guide:has(status:contains('" + $pubstate + "'), status:contains('" + $privstate + "'))");
```

You could also use `filter` to check the content of the `status` elements:

```
$(data).find('guide').filter(function() {
    var $status = $(this).find('status');
    var statusText = $status.text();
    return statusText.indexOf($pubstate) != -1 || statusText.indexOf($privstate) != -1;
});
```